# TypeError: object of type 'PSKeyword' has no len()

Tags: python, python-3.x, pdfminer

I want to convert PDF to text files to process the document. I am using python 3.x and 
While I try to convert pdftotext using **PDFMiner**. some pdf can't be parsed and leads to the error(python 3.x)
This is the code which converts the pdf to text. onlyfiles[2] is the pdf file
name. couldn't figure out the error message.

```
import io
from pdfminer.converter import TextConverter
from pdfminer.pdfinterp import PDFPageInterpreter
from pdfminer.pdfinterp import PDFResourceManager
from pdfminer.pdfpage import PDFPage
def extract_text_by_page(pdf_path):
    with open(pdf_path, 'rb') as fh:
        for page in PDFPage.get_pages(fh, 
                                      caching=True,
                                      check_extractable=True):
            resource_manager = PDFResourceManager()
            fake_file_handle = io.StringIO()
            converter = TextConverter(resource_manager, fake_file_handle)
            page_interpreter = PDFPageInterpreter(resource_manager, converter)
            page_interpreter.process_page(page)
            text = fake_file_handle.getvalue()
            yield text
            # close open handles
            converter.close()
            fake_file_handle.close()
def extract_text(pdf_path):
    for page in extract_text_by_page(pdf_path):
        print(page)
        print()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(extract_text(onlyfiles[2]))
```

The error message is:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-19-7fed22ec1779> in <module>
     25         print()
     26 if __name__ == '__main__':
---> 27     print(extract_text(onlyfiles[2]))

<ipython-input-19-7fed22ec1779> in extract_text(pdf_path)
     21             fake_file_handle.close()
     22 def extract_text(pdf_path):
---> 23     for page in extract_text_by_page(pdf_path):
     24         print(page)
     25         print()

<ipython-input-19-7fed22ec1779> in extract_text_by_page(pdf_path)
     14             converter = TextConverter(resource_manager, fake_file_handle)
     15             page_interpreter = PDFPageInterpreter(resource_manager, converter)
---> 16             page_interpreter.process_page(page)
     17             text = fake_file_handle.getvalue()
     18             yield text

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\pdfminer\pdfinterp.py in process_page(self, page)
    850             ctm = (1, 0, 0, 1, -x0, -y0)
    851         self.device.begin_page(page, ctm)
--> 852         self.render_contents(page.resources, page.contents, ctm=ctm)
    853         self.device.end_page(page)
    854         return

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\pdfminer\pdfinterp.py in render_contents(self, resources, streams, ctm)
    862         self.init_resources(resources)
    863         self.init_state(ctm)
--> 864         self.execute(list_value(streams))
    865         return
    866 

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\pdfminer\pdfinterp.py in execute(self, streams)
    886                         log.debug('exec: %s %r', name, args)
    887                         if len(args) == nargs:
--> 888                             func(*args)
    889                     else:
    890                         log.debug('exec: %s', name)

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\pdfminer\pdfinterp.py in do_TJ(self, seq)
    770                 raise PDFInterpreterError('No font specified!')
    771             return
--> 772         self.device.render_string(self.textstate, seq, self.ncs, self.graphicstate.copy())
    773         return
    774 

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\pdfminer\pdfdevice.py in render_string(self, textstate, seq, ncs, graphicstate)
     85             textstate.linematrix = self.render_string_horizontal(
     86                 seq, matrix, textstate.linematrix, font, fontsize,
---> 87                 scaling, charspace, wordspace, rise, dxscale, ncs, graphicstate)
     88         return
     89 

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\pdfminer\pdfdevice.py in render_string_horizontal(self, seq, matrix, pos, font, fontsize, scaling, charspace, wordspace, rise, dxscale, ncs, graphicstate)
     98                 needcharspace = True
     99             else:
--> 100                 for cid in font.decode(obj):
    101                     if needcharspace:
    102                         x += charspace

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\pdfminer\pdffont.py in decode(self, bytes)
    717 
    718     def decode(self, bytes):
--> 719         return self.cmap.decode(bytes)
    720 
    721     def char_disp(self, cid):

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\pdfminer\cmapdb.py in decode(self, code)
    125 
    126     def decode(self, code):
--> 127         n = len(code)//2
    128         if n:
    129             return struct.unpack('>%dH' % n, code)

TypeError: object of type 'PSKeyword' has no len()
```

Comment: Maybe the pdf you are trying to convert into text has been made pdf from image files.

Comment: It is difficult to guess the problem just from error message. Sample code which causes this error might help better.

Comment: No it's not an image I have checked